# Remove the index rows, (not column) in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, rows

I have problem with python pandas. I need to remove the index rows (not columns)

I'm trying with this command.

```
data_last.to_csv (r'D:\Matkelp3.csv',index=False)
```

I still get the [index row in the first line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OcaEa.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to also specify `header=False`:

```
data_last.to_csv(r'D:\Matkelp3.csv', index=False, header=False)
```